# suppress/delete xml content based on attribute value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml like

```
<xml>
   <Text>
       <body>
       <para type="new"> This para needs to be suppress </para> 
       <para type="old"> This is an old para </para> 
       </body>     
  </Text>    
</xml>
```

I want to suppress the body/para/@type='new' which I can do using following templete

```
<xsl:template match="para[@type='new']">
</xsl:template>
```

Having said that, I want to actually add another condition that if body does not contain any other element other then para/@type='new' then whole body element should be removed.

So

```
 <xml>
   <Text>
       <body>
       <para type="new"> This para needs to be suppress </para> 
       </body>     
  </Text>    
</xml>
```

should return

```
<xml>
   <Text>
   </Text>    
</xml>
```

and

```
<xml>
    <Text>
       <body>
          <para type="new"> This para needs to be suppress </para> 
          <para type="old"> This is an old para </para> 
       </body>     
    </Text>    
</xml>
```

should return

```
<xml>
   <Text>
       <body>
       <para type="old"> This is an old para </para> 
       </body>     
  </Text>    
</xml>
```

Any help or hint how to do that...

Comment: Could you show us what the template for the body element looks like, if you have one? Or your whole XSLT if it's not too long.

Comment: Also, what should happen if you have a **body** element with no child elements at all?

Comment: Will the body always have 0 or 1 "new" paras and 0 or 1 "old" paras and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about one more template:

```
<xsl:template match="Text[count(body/*) = count(body/para[@type = 'new'])]" />
```

Comment: Excelent Thanks Rishe... Can we also remove Text node based on above conditions?

Comment: Could you show us your whole XSL, if it's not too large? Hard to give an informed answer otherwise.

Comment: I have only these 2 rules in XSL i-e  <xsl:template match="body[not(*[not(self::para and @type = 'new')])]" />

  <xsl:template match="para[@type='new']" />. 
Can we just apply the second tempalte to Text instead of "body" so that Text element will get removed.

Comment: That's the entire XSL?  If that's the case, I'd expect it to be hardly outputting anything at all.  Could you please edit your question to include the whole XSL?  Everything between the starting and ending `<xsl:stylesheet>`.

Comment: Yes it will be an empty output like this <xml></xml>.

Comment: I see.  I misunderstood your question a bit.  Please try the above modification.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way

```
<xsl:template match="body[para[@type='new']][not(*[2])]" />
```

i.e. Match a **body** element with a **para** element of type 'new' but which does not a second element.